# # customers placed # orders query

Tags: sql-server

Can you tell me in the last 12 months how many customers placed

- 1 order
- 2 orders
- 3 orders
- 4 orders
- 5 or more orders

1 order              800,000 customers        800,000 orders
2 orders            100,000 customers        200,000 orders
3 orders            30,000 customers          90,000 orders
Etc.

Comment: how do i do this query?

Comment: select count(distinct o.OrigOrderid) as Orderscount, count(distinct o.BilltoPersonId) as UniqueCustomers
from indo.dbo.Orders o
where o.SourceId = 80 and o.isCancelled = 0  and o.isTransacted = 1 and o.DateOrdered >= '4/1/14'
Group By o.BilltoPersonId

Comment: this gives me count of every unique customer which is all 1 and then the order count

Comment: Well isn't that what you want? If you want real help you need to provide some details. Specifically the table structures and some sample data. sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to start.

Comment: The answer is 800.000, 100.000, 200.000, 30.000, 90.000, etc. For more details, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want except it wont sum over 5 - it will shpw you the breakdown as many there are (so if a customer made 50 orders there will a row for that:

```
with d1 as 
(select COUNT(*) as [Number of Orders], row_number() 
    over (order by custid ) as [How Many Orders] 
from t2 group by custid)
     select * from d1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, here is what you need.
I removed the "SourceId = 80" since I don't know the purpose of this condition.

```
SELECT  NbOrdersPerCustomer.NBOrders,
        COUNT(NbOrdersPerCustomer.CustomerId)
FROM (  SELECT  CustomerId = o.BilltoPersonId,
                NBOrders = COUNT(o.OrigOrderid)
        FROM indo.dbo.Orders o
        WHERE o.isCancelled = 0 
        AND o.isTransacted = 1 
        AND o.DateOrdered >= '4/1/14' 
        GROUP BY o.BilltoPersonId) AS NbOrdersPerCustomer
GROUP BY NbOrdersPerCustomer.NBOrders
```